# Converting NSDictionary to NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Whats the difference between, these two syntax to convert NSDictionary to NSArray?

//replyInfo is NSDictionary

```
     NSArray *values=[[NSArray alloc]init];
     values = [replyInfo valueForKey:@"response"];//when this?
     values = [replyInfo allValues];//when this?
```

Comment: Are you aware that you are creating an `NSArray` and then immediately throwing it away and overwriting the `values` variable?

Comment: Can you display response so we can better understand it.

Comment: `valueForKey:` is a key-value-coding method with special behavior. Basically you shouldn't use it at all to get a single value for a key. Use `objectForKey:` instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
values = [replyInfo valueForKey:@"response"];
```

This gives you value for particular key from dictionary.

Where in `values = [replyInfo allValues];`  returns a new array containing the dictionary’s values

`values = [replyInfo allKeys];` will return you array of all keys in dictionary.

**When to use:**

- When you want to access particular item from dictionary go for

  ```
  values = [replyInfo valueForKey:@"response"];
  ```
- When you want to do something with all values like iterate through all values or somethning go  for

  ```
  values = [replyInfo allValues];
  ```

Comment: but, replyInfo allValues- giving all values of dictionary at 0 index. I want to get each data values[0],values[1]..like this?

Comment: Thats beacuse your replyInfo have only one value

Comment: response is the only key, values are different data in an array which was converted to dictionary

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are getting the response as given below,

```
{
"response" : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}
```

Then,

```
values = [replyInfo allValues];
```

will put the data like this.

```
values[0] = NSArray ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
values[1] = nil
```

Now, to access such data; we can do as follows,

```
array = [values objectAtIndex:0];
```

Which can be resulted as,

```
array[0] = 1
array[1] = 2
array[2] = 3
array[3] = 4
array[4] = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

allValues : Its return type is an array. And It gives you the values of the dictionary (Not the keys). And return nil if dict is empty.

valueForKey : Its return type is id. It means this method can give any object (like NSArray, NSDictionary, NSString, etc.) in return.

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this:

```
successCallback(@[resultMessage]);
```

where resultMessage is NSDictionary and successCallback accept NSArray